# Publish slow and how does two updates work?

Tags: android

If one publish two apk versions one after each other, incrementing the android:versionCode

1. What happens if a user two days later makes an update, does he/she get both or only the latest
   update?
2. If one get both updates, is there a way to say update only the last one?
3. Lately when publishing and app it takes so long before it's active as an update on Play,
   it used to be very fast, now it varies a lot and sometime it takes a day or more.
   Especially if you do a couple after another, any thoughts, your experience?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really difficult to explain the mechanism employed by Google Play internally, unless done so by a Google Employee (which I doubt they will on a public fora).

1. I doubt if uploading one update followed immediately by another, will have any bearing on which update will be made available. I think that is the case because you have to deactivate the earlier APK before activating the new APK. The new Google Play website does that automatically. Again, this will have to be confirmed by someone who is aware of how things work.
2. Since the older of the two will have been deactivated by you while pushing the second update, I don't think the user will see the first update published.
3. I feel, considering that Google Play is now available in more countries than before, that could account for the delays that one sees before updates are available. Again, this is a very subjective behavior. Some are seeing updates within a couple of hours and some are taking longer.

Answer (score 0):

1. User always gets the latest version

   - In other words, if you have code that handles updates, such as SQLite DB schema updates you should be ready to upgrade from any older version.
2. {}
3. I'm not sure exactly why.. But now, Google runs the [Bouncer](http://googlemobile.blogspot.co.nz/2012/02/android-and-security.html) as a security and quality measure which may slow down the publish time a bot. (Although Google said that it runs after the publishing, and shouldn't affect publishing speed.)

   - Google now does some things for apps it didn't do before. Such as splitting the APKs for device types (so a device only receives the resources that it requires) .etc. But I don't see how this can severely affect publish time as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

User will get update available in GP at the moment of update.
Time between publishing and availablity can vary from minutes to hours.